# SAS delete table if 0 Observastions

Tags: sas

Is there a procedure that will check to see if a table has 0 observations, and if so then delete it? I assumed there could be an easier way besides manually checking and deleting each table. I'm using a loop command and most of the tables I generate with it will have data but several will have 0 observations.

Thanks if anyone can help.

Comment: You may have a better solution than looping and creating empty tables, depending on what you're doing; oftentimes BY group processing is superior to looping code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you don't have any reason not to trust the metadata, you could look at dictionary.tables:

```
proc sql;
select memname from dictionary.tables 
  where libname='WORK' and nobs=0;
quit;
```

So for example you could pull that into a macro variable and delete the tables in a PROC SQL or PROC DATASETS statement.

```
proc sql;
select memname into :dellist separated by ' ' from dictionary.tables 
  where libname='WORK' and nobs=0;
quit;

proc datasets nolist;
delete &dellist;
quit;
```

Comment: If rows have been deleted using 'delete from' in proc sql, or 'remove' in a data step with modify, then NLOBS (number of logical observations) should be used instead of NOBS.

Comment: This is what I ended up using. Sorry for the formatting.
    proc sql noprint ; 
    select memname into :deletelist separated by ' ' 
    from dictionary.tables 
    where libname='WORK'  and nobs eq 0; 
    quit; 

    proc datasets nolist; 
    delete &deletelist; 
    quit;